# Getting Solona Notifications

Tags: python

Anyone have any idea how I can get burn or mint status of any token that triggers these functions?

Theres a current tg bot that does this and im not sure how they do it... they get liqudity and decimal information as well along with the transaction links.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it lacks information about the problem. Please provide information about the bot, the protocol on Solana, and the issue faced.